# How does netty 3.3.1 ChannelLocal get emptied to prevent memory leak?

Tags: netty

So, when sharing items across handlers on a channel, ChannelLocal (with attendant put and get) are the solution in 3.3.1.

When I am done with my handler chain, does the ChannelLocal automatically realize my Channel is closed and empty it's entry in the ChannelLocal?  Or do I need to explicitly "null" out or empty out the ChannelLocal once I'm done with my shared object?

IE, will I have a memory leak if I use ChannelLocal and don't explicitly null out the items I'm putting into it when I'm done with them?

Digging through the source code comments left me unsure about how Garbage Collection interacts with the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you construct ChannelLocal with parameter true it get cleaned up automaticly once the Channel is closed. Otherwise you need todo it by your own. Default is to construct it with false.

See [1].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelLocal.html#127

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed!  Just missed that one somehow.